# UI freezes when using AsyncTask, ProgressDialog , AlertDialog and app minimization/restore

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

First, this particualr question has not been responded for my specific problem. So do not mark as duplicate because I found no valid responses in StackOverflow yet.

Consider this code:

```
package xxx.MyActivity;

import com.xxx.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,
                    getText(R.string.activity_dialog_generic_title),
                    getText(R.string.activity_reading), true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setMessage("dialog message");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes", null);
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no", null);
            alertDialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int i = 0;
            while (++i < 10) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both `progressDialog` and `alertDialog` are variables of the activity. Now:

1. Start activity
2. Wait for progress to be displayed
3. "Minimize" app using Home button
4. Wait 10 seconds
5. Return to the app

And I so no alert dialog and the UI is freezed (and grayed like when dialog is displayed but there's no dialog on the screen). Back button has no effect.

**EDIT:**

Adding this code in onPostExecute():

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new AlertDialog.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

The UI still looks freezed but a touch on the screen (a dialog cancel) will close the activity (as expected: finish()).

I also tryed to comment the line `alertDialog.show();`: no freezed UI, so the problem is with `AlertDialog`.

Comment: This code will not even compile. You cannot return true on a method that returns Void. It may be difficult to diagnose a problem, when you have perhaps edited out what is causing the problem. In any case, you are probably looking for: private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

Comment: For what it is worth, once changing to Boolean, you code has no failures. It is running completely as you expect it to.

Comment: I corrected the code. The problems is not on return true.

Comment: i tried this code with all strings instead of Void and it is working fine

Comment: @Seraphim please try with some other data type instead of Void as you cannot have array of void data types.

Comment: I corrected the code again, it compiles for me

Comment: I am using the exact same code above. It compiles and runs. I follow the instructions given, and I see absolutely no failures.

Comment: The problem for me is when the sys call alertDialgo.show() and the activity is paused, the ui freezes. I can replicate this behaviour all the time.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using currently?

Comment: I posted the code I'm using! :) I found also a solution, look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the issue.

Using a variable `showAlert` inside the Activity, I can know, when the Activity is resumed, if an alert was previously shown. If true **I force the dialog.show()**.

No it works as expected. Follow the use of `showAlert` variable.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    private volatile boolean showAlert;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        try {
            if (alertDialog != null) {
                if (showAlert) {
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showAlert = false;

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,
                    getText(R.string.activity_dialog_generic_title),
                    getText(R.string.activity_reading), true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setMessage("dialog message");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes", null);
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no", null);
            alertDialog.show();
            showAlert = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int i = 0;
            while (++i < 10) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```